# PowerShell unable to get [System.Globalization.CultureInfo] remotely using WMI

Tags: powershell

I need to modify the following code to allow the WMI Object to retrieve **[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]** value of the remote server.

The existing code is partially working, but not the **Locale** column which is always empty and not throwing any error.

```
function Get-OSlanguage ($oscode)
{
    switch ($oscode)
    {
        1033 { "English" };
        1049 { "Russian" };
        1031 { "German" };
        default { "Unknown" }
    }
}

$SearchBase = (Get-ADObject -SearchBase (Get-ADRootDSE).defaultNamingContext -Filter { Name -eq "Servers" }).DistinguishedName

$results = Get-ADComputer -SearchBase $SearchBase -Filter { OperatingSystem -like "Windows*Server*" } |
ForEach-Object {
    $Computer = $_.Name
    $os = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $Computer
    $tz = Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_TimeZone -ComputerName $Computer
    $ntpsource = w32tm /query /computer:$Computer /source
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'Name'   = $_.Name
        'Locale' = [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]([int]("0x" + $os.Locale)).DisplayName
        'OS language' = Get-OSlanguage $os.OSlanguage
        'TimeZone Caption' = $tz.Caption
        'TimeZone StandardName' = $tz.StandardName
        'TimeZone DaylightName' = $tz.DaylightName
        'NTP source' = $ntpsource.Trim()
    }
}

$results | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\ServerInfo.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

What can I try next?

Comment: Use either `[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::GetCultureInfo([int]$os.OSlanguage).DisplayName` or 
`[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::GetCultureInfo([int]('0x{0:X4}' -f $os.Locale)).DisplayName`. P.S. You can shorten `[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]` to just `[CultureInfo]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from my comment, here's a rewrite of your code using `Invoke-Command` to run the code on all Windows Servers at once.
It is also using the newer `Get-CimInstance` cmdlets instead of `Get-WmiObject`

```
$SearchBase = (Get-ADObject -SearchBase (Get-ADRootDSE).defaultNamingContext -Filter "Name -eq 'Servers'").DistinguishedName

$machines = (Get-ADComputer -SearchBase $SearchBase -Filter "OperatingSystem -like 'Windows*Server*'").Name
$results = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $machines -ScriptBlock {
    $os = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem 
    $tz = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_TimeZone
    $ntpsource = w32tm /query /computer:$Computer /source
    $language  = try { [CultureInfo]::GetCultureInfo([int]$os.OSlanguage).EnglishName -replace '^([^\(]+).*', '$1' }
                 catch { 'Unknown' }
    $locale    = try { [CultureInfo]::GetCultureInfo([int]('0x{0:X4}' -f $os.Locale)).DisplayName }
                 catch { 'Unknown' }

    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'ComputerName'          = $env:COMPUTERNAME
        'Locale'                = $locale
        'OS language'           = $language.Trim()
        'TimeZone Caption'      = $tz.Caption
        'TimeZone StandardName' = $tz.StandardName
        'TimeZone DaylightName' = $tz.DaylightName
        'NTP source'            = $ntpsource.Trim()
    }
}

# remove the extra properties PowerShell added and save to CSV
$results | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty PS*, RunspaceId | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\ServerInfo.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Hi @Theo thank you for the update, somehow the 'OS language' still showing as Unknown for all servers, while the rest of the columns are OK?

Comment: @SeniorSystemsEngineer Ah, sorry. I forgot to cast `$os.OSlanguage` to `[int]`. Can you try again please?

Comment: @SeniorSystemsEngineer Explanation of the above: if GetCultureInfo receives a **string** it will retrieve the info using the specified culture **name**. In this case we have a culture identifying **number** (LCID), so we must cast to int

Comment: many thanks for the great assistance and the explanation, yes, it works now.
I appreciate it very muchly.